# If $A$ is an invertible, orthogonally diagonalizable $n$ x $n$ matrix...

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that if $A$ is an invertible, orthogonally diagonalizable $n$ x $n$ matrix, then $A^{-1}$ is also orthogonally diagonalizable.

Prove or give a counter example for if $A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix, then $A^{-1}$ is also symmetric positive definite.

These two proofs are, I assume, very similar, but I'm really not sure how to solve either of them...

Answer (score 2):

Fill in details: with $\;D\;$ diagonal and $\;P\;$ orthogonal:

$$A=P^{-1}DP\implies A^{-1}=P^{-1}D^{-1}P$$